# Trying to update Android SDK

Tags: android, android-version

In trying to update my SDK to the latest, some things installed, but others* didn't.

```
*SDK Platform Android 4.0, API14, revision 3
Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API15 revision 1
Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API14 revision 2
Sources for Android SDK, API14, revision 1
```

I got this err msg:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-= Warning ! =-
A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a program is uing that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.)
Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be accessing the directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14'. 
When ready, press YES to try again.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Even after manually stopping a McAfee service and MS Malware service (MS Security Essentials) via

Task Manager, I still got this err msg.

The error highlighted (in brick red) in the Android SDK Manager Log is:

```
Failed to rename C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-14 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\PlatformPackage.old01.
```

- Is this something I should do manually - would that allow the update to take place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you started the update from eclipse, it might help to exit eclipse, and go to your sdk/utils directory and start de SDKmanager from there. This worked for me after I got the same message today.

Comment: OK - what is the command to download/install everything available?

Comment: If you open the SDKmanager, it will check various XML files and show if there is something to be updated. It was quite self-explanatory on my system

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now - run the .exe standalone. That pretty much worked for me (although I had to run as Administrator); the Google API 15 revision 1 still won't install, though...

Comment: After I re-started it, it finally showed Googapi 15.1 as being installed. So all is well that ends convolutedly.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I probably would have to curse out a few million dust mites otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't  know if this will help but generally a few things might cause problems like:

Having a device connected or the emulator running.

Forgetting to run the Android SDK tool as Administrator.

Some errors can occur with the windows "program files (x86)" path. I tend to just move the Android folder to the root C path so the SDK would be at C:\Android

If you've covered all that then I'm not sure. It should usually just work without you having to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

That is the answer. C:\Program Files is protected against user modification.

Unfortunately, the SDK Manager does not escalate it's privileges. That would be a nice addition to the Windows version.